# All shapes with X miles or meters using SqlGeometery

Tags: sql-server, sqlgeometry

My table uses a SqlGeometery in SRID 3857.

Given a point, how would I find all shapes within a X miles or meters radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a [Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933963.aspx) around the point and run [STIntersects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933962.aspx) to get all intersection shapes. Just make sure you put an index on the Geometry column otherwise it could get slow.
Note that x is in meters (eg 10m).

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyGeometryShapesColumn.STIntersects(@MyGeometryPoint.STBuffer(10)) = 1;
```